# How to use jaxrs-analyzer standalone to create swagger specific documents?

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

My project is creating different jar files. These are located in different locations. I need to run jaxrs-analyzer.jar to generate my swagger.json file.

How can I give multiple jar location to the jaxrs-analyzer? Or is there any way to run this jar file while built the project through ant?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate all files in your classpath. I have this in my ant file:

```
  <echo message="Generating swagger..."/>
    <java jar="jaxrs-analyzer/jaxrs-analyzer.jar" fork="true" output="salida">
        <arg line="-b swagger"/>
        <arg line="-n &quot;My Project&quot;"/>
        <arg line="-v v1.0"/>
        <arg line="-d domain-for-my-project.com/path"/>
        <arg line="-o swagger.js"/>
        <arg line="-cp my-library/library1.jar"/>
        <arg line="-cp my-library/library2.jar"/>
        <arg line="-cp my-library/library3.jar"/>
        <arg line="build/classes/"/>
    </java>
    <delete file="salida"/>
```